# Trying to find title of book about feline man who ride large cats

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Looking for a series of books about an old man who starts out on a yacht but something happens and he wakes up in the body of a young feline-like man.

He also has a telepathic link to a large cat that he has to convince that he did not kill the original inhabitant of the body.

Comment: omg furries! hide the children!

Comment: @Lohoris - Did somebody say furries? http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-IZB0leWC1_A/UIkasvtH06I/AAAAAAAAClI/od02Wek7C-0/s1600/hermione_cat_tf_by_dastanprince-d37s2wr.png

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167902/a-book-where-a-man-inhabits-the-body-of-a-dying-man-and-befriends-a-telepathic-c

Answer (score 9):

This is the [Gandalara Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandalara_Cycle), a series of seven fantasy books written by Randall Garrett and Vicki Ann Heydron.

[image]

Per wikipedia;

> Ricardo Carillo, an aging language professor with a terminal illness,
>   is flirting with a captivating young woman on a Mediterranean cruise
>   ship. They both watch with wonder, and a growing horror, as a
>   dazzlingly beautiful star quickly grows to engulf the sky and then
>   crashes into the ship.
>
> Ricardo awakens in a blinding hot desert, with no idea where he is and
>   a dead man by his side.
>
> Without knowing how or why, Ricardo finds himself inhabiting the body
>   of a strong, healthy, young man named Markasset. Ricardo quickly
>   learns that Markasset is wanted for murder and the theft of a precious
>   and powerful gemstone, the Ra'ira. Ricardo has only a smattering of
>   Markasset's memories, and no idea if he is guilty or innocent. But
>   with the help of a giant warcat named Keeshah, with whom he shares a
>   telepathic bond, and the beautiful illusionist, Tarani, Ricardo sets
>   out on a quest to recover the missing gemstone and clear his new name.